# decoding a base64 string and reencoding the returned bytes doesn't return same string

Tags: java, base64

I am doing a simple decoding of a base64 string. When I re-encode I don't get the same string back. What am I missing ?

```
String base64 = "R3df789GSfsb2edfSFSDFuikuikk2349GSfsb2edfSvFSDFR3df789GSfsb2edf";
byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64.getBytes());
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(decoded);
```

You can see that the string `encoded` is not the same as the input string `base64`:

```
R3df789GSfsb2edfSFSDFuikuikk2349GSfsb2edfSvFSDFR3df789GSfsb2edc=
```

[image]

Comment: @KarolDowbecki The encoded bytes is binary data, not text.

Comment: Ok, I got the encoded string from somewhere. So I don't know the actual source string. You are right though I've had better luck with other encoded strings. I was just wondering what it is that is off with this.

@Andreas The `base64` string is the result of an encoded string.

Comment: "The **encoded** **bytes**" is shorthand for "the **bytes** that were **encoded** to Base64"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base64 encodes 3 bytes *(3 * 8 = 24 bits)* into 4 characters, by choosing from 64 *(6 bits)* displayable characters *(4 * 6 = 24 bits)*. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for detailed description of how it works.

So, for every 4 encoded characters, you'll get 3 bytes. Your input is:

`R3df 789G Sfsb 2edf SFSD Fuik uikk 2349 GSfs b2ed fSvF SDFR 3df7 89GS fsb2 edf`

As you can see, that is 15 blocks of 4 characters, and a final block of only 3 characters. 3 characters *(3 * 6 = 18 bits)* can store 2 bytes *(2 * 8 = 16 bits)*, leaving 2 unused bits. These 2 bits can have any value, since they are unused, but the standard is for such *extra* bits to be set to 0.

Your input is from a Base64 encoded that chose to set the extra bits to 1, so last character is `f`, not the standard `c`.

It is also quite common, though not always required, to pad the encoded text to full blocks by adding 1 or 2 `=` signs at the end. So, standard of using 0 for extra bits, and adding padding, the final block becomes `edc=`, but it decodes to the same bytes as the non-standard final block of `edf`.